# All points of open sets are limit points

Tags: functional-analysis

It is true that any point in the open set $U$ which is a subset of $R^2$ is also a limit point of $U$. Is it true for all $R^n$? It feels like it should be true. Is there a proof for this?

Comment: Is $\Bbb R^2$ open in $\Bbb R^2$?

Answer (score 0):

If $U$ is open, all points of $U$ are interior. This means that for any point $x \in U$, there is an $\epsilon$ such that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset U$. Consider the shrinking family of balls $B(x, \epsilon/n)$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We can consider $B(x, \epsilon/n - B(x, \epsilon/(n+1))$. This is a non-empty subset of the ball. Choose a point in this set for each $n$. This forms a sequence converging to $x$, and so shows that $x$ is a limit point of $U$. Since this is true for every $x$, we're done.

Notice that this works in every dimension - all we needed was that we had a decreasing family of balls. Thus it works in much more generality as well, although in a more general setting, you may need a different decreasing family.